# How to speed up integration tests using SQL Server Dev Edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, unit-testing, c#-4.0, nunit, resharper

We have a suite of applications developed in C# and C++ and using SQL Server as the back end. Integration tests are developed with NUnit, and they take more than two minutes to run. To speed up integration tests, we are using the following:

- Tests run on the same workstation, so no network delays
- Test databases are created on DataRam RAM Disk, which is fast
- Test fixtures run in parallel, currently up to four at a time
- Most test data is bulk loaded using table-valued parameters.

What else can be done to speed up automated integration tests?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to answer this question. Tests are code, so this question is asking "how can I make my code run faster?" and obviously there's no simple answer to that question. If you can identify a couple of tests that take up most of the time, or if there's a specific performance issue that you've observed and measured then someone may be able to help if you can post some code and possibly the execution plans too. Have you profiled the test executions to see where the time is going? And depending on what your test are doing and how many there are, 2 minutes could be good.

Comment: Yeah, my tests take 15 minutes to finish!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very, very old but I'll post my answer anyway.

It may sound stupid but: **Write less integration tests and more unit tests**. Integration test only at your applications boundaries (as in "when you pass control to code you do not own").

My opinion on this is inspired by [J.B. Reinsberger](http://www.jbrains.ca/). If you want, you can listen to a talk he gave on this topic. He is way better in explaining this than I am. Here is a link to the video:

http://vimeo.com/80533536

Answer (score 0):

I do not like this answer, write less integration tests as it is wrong. Our application is data heavy. Most of our code is logic around the data. So without integration tests we have just trivial unit tests (which i think should still be written).

Our Integration Tests run for 1 hour. Thousands of tests. They have brought us a tremendous value.

I think you should analyse the slow tests and why they are slow. Look if multiple tests can reuse the data without dropping and recreating it from scratch. 
Divide tests into areas so you do not always need to run every test. 
Use an existing database snapshot instead of recreating the database.